# Is there any difference between a global variable and a property of the Global Object

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I was reading the following analysis from David Mark about the js framework "Sencha": https://gist.github.com/3279190 and in there he states...

> What they wanted was a global variable, but they ended up with is a property of the Global Object. According the specifications and (and implementation history) there are enough differences between the two that care is required not to mix them up (as is done here).

...but as far as I was aware there wasn't any difference between `var my_global = 123;` and (in a browser environment) `window.my_global = 123;` (in that example I assumed the environment was a browser - hence the use of `window`, but I could have just used `this.my_global` instead as obviously the Global Object would be different when run in different environments).

But ignoring that minor discrepancy is there a difference between assigning a property to the Global Object and creating a global variable? I thought not, and that creating a global variable was just another way to assign a property to the Global Object.

I believe there can be an issue in some browsers if they had an element with an id of "my_global" then apparently that can cause problems with JavaScript referencing the right thing, but I'm not sure how/what causes that problem (e.g. does assigning a property to the Global Object cause the element id issue to occur, or is it declaring a global variable that causes the element id issue?)

Can someone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update, April 2020**

As noted in the comments by D. Pardal, the first sentence below, written in 2012, is no longer always true in environments that support [ES Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) ([spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-modules)). Inside an ES module, a `var` statement does not produce a property of the global object.

**Original answer**

A variable created using `var` in the global scope does create a property of the global object. However, this property has different behaviour from a property of the global object that has not been created using `var`.

Firstly, there is a difference in how a variable declaration is executed: a `var` statement in the global scope creates a property of the global object before any code is executed, an effect commonly known as *hoisting*, well documented around the web (see references below).

Secondly, the global variable, unlike a property of the global object that has not been created with `var`, cannot be deleted using the `delete` operator (although this is [not true in older versions of IE](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#ie_bugs)). `delete` cannot be used to delete variables. This difference is down to internal [property attributes](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) that every object property has. These attributes are specified in the ECMAScript specification. In ECMAScript 5 terms, `var foo = "bar"` creates a property `foo` of the global object with the `[[Configurable]]` attribute `false` whereas `this.foo = "bar"` (in global scope) creates a `foo` property with `[[Configurable]]` attribute `true`.

References:

- Dmitry Soshnikov has written at length about this in his excellent
  series of articles, [ECMAScript 262-3 in detail](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/tag/ecma-262-3/). I recommend
  reading all of chapter 2, but the most relevant section is called
  [About Variables](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#about-variables).
- The [kangax article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#ie_bugs) linked earlier contains a lot of
  relevant information and details of browser bugs and deviations,
  plus further quirks concerning `window`.
- Angus Croll's [Variables vs. Properties in JavaScript article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/), which links to many of the same resources as this answer.
- The spec: [ECMAScript 5.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Comment: Thanks for answering this so clearly. I kind of had an idea when it came to declaration with `var` vs not, but had no idea about the `[[Configurable]]` attribute.

Comment: One of the greatest answers I've seen on SO. Seriously.

Comment: "A variable created using `var` in the global scope does create a property of the global object." Not always, being ES modules a notable exception.

Comment: @D.Pardal: True. This was correct at time of writing, though. I'll add a note.

Comment: Probably also worth updating the reference to the specification to either the [latest published at ECMA-international.org](https://262.ecma-international.org) or [latest draft on GitHub](https://tc39.es/ecma262/).

Comment: @RobG The MDN page is easier to learn from than the spec, so I added rather than replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any practical difference but there sure is some difference between referencing as global or as window.var. A simple example:

`'use_strict';
console.info(window.foo);
console.info(foo);`

window.foo will simply return undefined. foo will give undefined as error.
So yes, they are different. But in good code(my example is very bad code) it doesn't look like there is any difference. (but if there is, I really like to know more about it :) )

Answer (score -2):

```
var count = 123

var global_object = {
    count:var = 456
console.log(this.count) //returns 456

}

console.log(count) //returns 123

console.log(global_object) //returns 456
```

Above, count is first defined as a global variable. Then, it is defined as a property within the global object. The definition within the global object is local to that object.

I see a problem with my answer now that didn't occur to me when I first posted this. In the most upvoted answer above I notice it is, correctly, shown that in the case of the global variable in the question "var" is used in its definition, but in the case of the global object, no "var" is used. I would still expect scope to come into play here (it would in ActionScript).

I have a couple other problems with the example above. count:var = is just wrong to me. Maybe that should be var count = 456. However; I would still expect a variable declared within a function to only have scope within that function. So the console.log expressions in the example should hold true.

Comment: Don't think this is what the OP is about?

Comment: `window` is a global object. `window.count === count //true`