# Are the terms "global property" and "global variable" synonyms?

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, scope, global-variables

The global object serves as the top-level lexical environment (the top of the scope-chain, if you will). This means that global properties may be accessed via direct references (like variables):

```
// global code
this.foo = 1;        // creating a global property
foo                  // accessing the global property via a direct reference
```

This also means that global variables may be accessed via property references:

```
// global code
var foo = 1;         // creating a global variable
this.foo             // accessing the global variable via a property reference
```

---

### INTERPRETATION 1

Now, based on the above information, it would seem that it would be appropriate to use the terms "global variable" an "global property" interchangeably, meaning that both terms **represent the exact same set of global bindings**.

---

However, there are two differences between a global variable created using `var` ,e.g. `var foo = 1;`, and a global property created through an assignment, e.g. `this.foo = 1;`:

1. Global variables are **statically scoped**, whereas global properties are **dynamically added** to the global environment:

   ```
   foo // => undefined
   bar // throws ReferenceError

   var foo = 1;
   this.bar = 1;
   ```

   So, global variables are bound *before* program evaluation, whereas global properties are bound *during* program evaluation, when the assignment is evaluated.
2. Global variables are non-configurable, i.e. they cannot be deleted (more specifically, their corresponding bindings cannot be removed from the environment subsequently), whereas global properties created through assignment *are* configurable.

   ```
   // the names "foo" and "bar" are bound to the global environment
   var foo = 1;
   this.bar = 1;

   // the binding "bar" can be removed from the global environment subsequently 
   delete this.bar; 

   // the binding "foo" cannot be removed subsequently
   ```

That being said, it should be noted that it is possible to create non-configurable global properties:

```
Object.defineProperty( this, 'bar', { value: 1 }); // non-configurable by default
```

---

### INTERPRETATION 2

Now, based on this new information, one could say that only statically scoped global bindings may be referred to as both global properties and global variables, whereas dynamically added global bindings are merely global properties, but not global variables, meaning that the term "global variable" represents **a subset** of the set represented by the term "global property", as in:

> All global variables are global properties
> Only statically scoped global properties are global variables

---

So, which interpretation is correct? Do both terms represent the same set of bindings, or is one a subset of the other?

---

### THE QUESTION

I do understand the term "global property" - a global property is a property of the global object. However, the term "global variable" appears to be **ambiguous**. Some use it as a synonym for "global property", while others define it to mean a global property which has been defined via a `var` statement. The intent of my question is to determine which of these two meanings is correct

Comment: What about implicit globals (`foobar = 1`, without `var`); are they equal to global properties or are they a third type?

Comment: @Bergi -- like I said in my answer, JS will go through the chain of function-scopes until it finds that var/prop, and if it doesn't find it, it will append the value to a property of the global object. In your specific case, you just happen to ***already*** be starting within the global object, so there's less traversing for the engine to do. For a proof, try `bob = "Bob"; delete bob; console.log(bob); // reference error - bob is not defined`

Comment: @Bergi Implicit globals are just regular global properties. So, `x = 1;` is equivalent to `window.x = 1;` (in the browser). (Btw, strict mode throws on the first one.)

Comment: @Norguard: Thanks. I already did that, I only needed a confirmation :-)

Comment: @Norguard "*already starting with the global object*" - What do you mean? You mean, since we're in global code, so there's no scope-traversal?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I mean the first line you type in a JS program is `bob = "Bob";` then you're inside of the global scope -- you're not inside of any other function. As such, scope-resolution still applies, but seeing as you're already in the global scope, you're already at the end-point of the scope-resolution chain. As such, it just means that the recursion chain (or stack, or whatever the particular engine is doing) is already at the end point, and as such, it will assign a global-property, the exact same way as if you wrote `var sayBob = function () { bob = "Bob"; }; sayBob();` but with less work

Comment: related: [Is there any difference between a global variable and a property of the Global Object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12439256/1048572)

Answer (score 5):

Well, you already know everything I would have said to differentiate between the edge-cases of variables and properties which are attached to `window`.

If you wanted to get really, really pedantic, I suppose that you could consider the global scope to be both a functional-scope *and* a scope in which the `window` object is extended with properties using the same hidden configuration settings as what is provided within the program (eg: vars can be reassigned but not deleted). So in that sense, as far as functionality is concerned, they are different, and reflect attributes of properties and variables, globally scoped.

And referring to them as such is totally fine.
But the majority of people out there don't even recognize the difference, let alone differentiate between the two terms.
Even the important JS authors out there have referred to setting a `global variable` accidentally, by omitting `var`, when really, JS scales the function scopes, and if it makes it to the global scope without hitting that name, it appends a `global property` with that data, rather than a `global variable`.

But that really sort of brings us to the crux -- a strong and stable and reliable JS application, living on a modern webpage along with other applications, really shouldn't be too concerned with the differences.
The goal is to use as few global properties and variables as possible, in that case.

Moreover, the danger of variable/property collision is the same, regardless of which it is.
Variables are immune to `delete`, but what are the chances that any useful program is going to `delete` a property it's never even set?

So personally, I think it's good to understand the edge-cases, but I also think that while the pedant in me wants to agree that there's a difference, and they are not coterminous, the pragmatist in me shudders to think of a world where people are actively using the global scope to the extent where this makes a large difference to them.

Answer (score 2):

A good explanation can be found [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/), but I'll shorten it down to answer your question. When you say:

> both terms represent the exact same set of global bindings.

...you're almost correct, but not quite. Property assignments like `this.foo = 1` are saved into the **global** object. Variable declarations like `var bar = 2` however are saved into the **variable** object.

When executing under global scope, *both the global object and the variable object are represented by the same object--the global object* (when you're executing in a browser, this is the `window` object).

I mention this because your explanation alone is insufficient to explain the behavior of this program:

```
// "this" refers to the global object. But global object is also acting as the
// variable object! Because of that, the following code works:

var foo = 1;
alert(this.foo);   // 1

(function() {

    // "this" still refers to the global object! But the *variable* object has
    // changed because we're now in the execution context of a function, thus
    // the behavior changes:

    var bar = 2;
    alert(this.foo);  // 1
    alert(this.bar);  // undefined

})();
```

This doesn't mean that global properties and global variables are identical however. There are three hidden flags on all properties: `ReadOnly`, `DontEnum`, and `DontDelete`.

When using implicit property declarations like `this.foo = 1`, the `DontDelete` attribute is set to `false`. When you use variable declarations like `var bar = 2`, the `DontDelete` attribute is set to `true`, thus representing the difference between them when you use the `delete` operator.

---

In response to your rephrased question:

> [T]he term "global variable" appears to be ambiguous. Some use it as a
>   synonym for "global property", while others define it to mean a global
>   property which has been defined via a var statement. The intent of my
>   question is to determine which of these two meanings is correct.

The term is not clearly defined, and therefore you are asking for nothing more than an opinion.

In general, the term "global property" is used when you create a variable using the syntax `this.foo = 1`, and the term "global variable" is used when you create a variable using the syntax `var bar = 2`. There's nothing more to discuss.

Neither term has a true bearing on what goes on behind the scenes, thus the best you can do is understand what actually goes on behind the scenes, which you have already done.

Further demanding an absolute definition on two arbitrary terms will simply cause you to be an unpopular person.

Comment: ★1★ I understand that in function code, the `this` value does *not* refer to the environment record. However, that is off-topic. I don't see how it's relevant for this question. (Note that the term "variable object" has been replaced by the term "environment record"). ★2★ You mention the `DontDelete` attribute. Notice how I already covered that information in my question (in the 2. list item). Also, notice that, as I stated in my question, it is possible to define non-configurable global properties, which means that configurability (specifically, deletability) is *not* an differentiator here.

Comment: ★3★ You mention that variable hoisting is the reason why variables **are not** statically scoped. That's not correct. Variable hoisting is the exact reason why variables **are** statically scoped. Static scoping means that the variable is defined throughout the code (it cannot be added or removed dynamically).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I misunderstood what you were going for with your example on scoping. With that said, what on earth are you asking? If you already have a clear understanding of how it works (all the way down to the actual *implementation*), then you know all there is to know. The only thing I can think of is that you're asking about whether it is a subset in a *mathematical sense*, in which case you are over thinking this to levels that transcend sanity.

Comment: My question is whether all global properties are also global variables, or whether only those global properties which have been created using the `var` statement, are global variables.

Comment: The terms "global properties" and "global variables" are artificial labels, not mathematical concepts! They're normally just used to reference how the value was created in code and nothing more. In the implementation, there is no notion of properties or variables, merely **values** (in this case, they both reside in the `window` object). As you've already figured out, using `var` sets the `DontDelete` flag on the value differently than when when you use a property, but there are exceptions (as you also figured out). You already know all there is to know.

Comment: I understand the behavior, but my question is about terminology. I *do* understand the term "global property" - a global property is a property of the global object. However, the term "global variable" appears to be **ambiguous**. Some use it as a synonym for "global property", while others define it to mean a global property which has been defined via a `var` statement. The intent of my question is to determine which of these two meanings is correct.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, and why do you believe that it needs an unambiguous definition? Languages (and English especially) are notorious for having definitions that are horribly unclear. (Examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences#Syntactic_ambiguity)

Comment: (continued) General usage in JavaScript is to use the terms variable/property based on how they are originally defined, but that label is arbitrary, and as you've seen, it can be ambiguous. The behind-the-scenes implementation represents the unambiguous truth, and that implementation is detached from the original code by the rules you already understand. You already know all there is to know.

Comment: Well, ambiguity is obviously not desirable - it can lead to confusion, and misunderstanding. We, as a JavaScript community, should work towards eliminating ambiguity from our terminology. That being said, I'd like to say that I appreciate this conversation. It helped me identify the core issue - which is the ambiguity of the term "global variable".