# Why is there a global object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that when we create a variable using the `var` keyword there is a property with the same name added to the `window` object (in a browser enviroment) but this creates (for me) a confusion, because I have to think about a normal global variable vs global object. Variables created with `let` keyword are not added to the global object and that creates a divergence between our global scope and the global object. So, why is this global object necessary in the first place? Why do something like `window.x` instead of using  x directly. What is the difference between the global scope and global object?

Comment: Declaring a variable with `var` only adds it to the global object if you declare it in the top-level scope. And you can use `x` directly. Though `var` is now considered bad practice (or code smell) and should be avoided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Please read the attcahed post. has lot of insights!

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456806/476

Comment: I guess the global object is not *necessary* and having it was considered a mistake in hindsight, that's why `let`/`const` declarations are now using just a global scope.

Comment: "*I have to thin[k] about a normal global variable vs global object*" - no, usually you shouldn't need to. What exactly is your worry?

Comment: I am relatively new to this stuff, so initially I thought that global object and global scope were the same thing. But they are not. I was confused because of that.

Answer (score 1):

### Why

It's hard to say exactly *why* this feature exists, but it's useful in some situations. For example, if you're using Webpack or some other packer or ES modules, variables delcared with `var` will *not* be stored in the global object and thus will *not* be accessible through other files. As such, if you want a variable to be available everywhere, you need to declare it directly via the global object (`globalThis.varName = value`).

### Global Scope vs Global Object

As I noted above, variables declared inside ES modules will not be stored in the global object. You can think of the properties on the global object as variables on a "super-global" scope, above the global scope.

While the global scope includes all variables decalerd with `var`, `let` or `const` outside any functions in a file, the global object may or may not include all variables decalerd with `var` outside any functions in a file.

What ends up in the global object, the scope of the global object and how many global objects there are depends on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read the mind of Brendan Eich, but I can take an educated guess as to why the global object exists:

First of all, the design of JavaScript is kept very simple: Records (the place where variable values get stored) and Objects are very similar. Both are basically a collection of key-value pairs. That simplifies the design (e.g. `a = 1` works the same way as `a.b = 1`) and has the side effect that objects can easily be used as records (e.g. with the `with` statement).

Secondly you might also want to refer to global variables although the variable got shadowed. That can easily be achieved with having a self reference inside the global object / record (`window` is just a self reference).

Therefore it does make sense that `var` creates a variable in the global record, which, you can also refer to via `window.`.

Actually that `const` and `let` do not create a variable on the global scope is the inconsistency, but with that modularity gets achieved.